# Compare datetime on select with date only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare two datetimes based upon if their date is shared.
This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM XXX
WHERE CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE)
```

However, I wanted to actually get the result as an extra column:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE)
    , *
FROM XXX
```

The latter doesn't work as SQLServer complains that the syntax is invalid.
Any suggestions?

The result should be as follows:

```
LoadDateLAG | LoadDateLEAD | (LoadDateLAG = LoadDateLEAD) [as bit]
```

I need this functionality to compress a historized table
 - remove unnecessary entries (e.g., only keep the last entry per day).

Comment: What is your expected result? can you show a example?

Comment: What are you hoping to see in that extra column?   Your intent is not clear from your broken attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+

```
SELECT IIF(CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE),1,0),* FROM XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CASE WHEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
    LoadDateLAG, LoadDateLEAD,
    CASE WHEN CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isDateEquals
FROM XXX
-- WHERE CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE)
```

In case you also want to show the `DATE` values too (instead of `DATETIME)`, you can use the following `SELECT`:

```
 SELECT 
    CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) AS LoadDateLAG,
    CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE) AS LoadDateLEAD,
    CASE WHEN CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isDateEquals
FROM XXX
-- WHERE CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE)
```

In case you want to show the `DATE` values (instead of 1 or 0) if equals, you can use the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    LoadDateLAG, LoadDateLEAD,
    CASE WHEN CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE) THEN CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) ELSE NULL END AS equalsDate
FROM XXX
-- WHERE CAST(LoadDateLAG AS DATE) = CAST(LoadDateLEAD AS DATE)
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30b0e/11/1